# How to restart a async method? Cancel previous run, await it and then start it

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a method `RestartAsync` which starts a method `DoSomethingAsync`. When `RestartAsync` is called again it should cancel `DoSomethingAsync`and await until it is finished (`DoSomethingAsync` can NOT be cancelled synchronously and it should NOT be called when a previous task is still in progress).

My first approach looked like this:

```
public async Task RestartTest()
{
    Task[] allTasks = { RestartAsync(), RestartAsync(), RestartAsync() } ;
    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}

private async Task RestartAsync()
{
    _cts.Cancel();
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await _somethingIsRunningTask;

    _somethingIsRunningTask = DoSomethingAsync(_cts.Token);

    await _somethingIsRunningTask;
}

private static int _numberOfStarts;

private async Task DoSomethingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _numberOfStarts++;
    int numberOfStarts = _numberOfStarts;

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfStarts + " Start to do something...");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // This operation can not be cancelled.
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfStarts + " Finished to do something...");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfStarts + " Cancelled to do something...");
    }
}
```

The actual output when calling RestartAsync three times looks like this (Note that the second run is cancelling and awaiting the first, but at the same time the third run is also awaiting the first instead of cancelling and awaiting the second one):

```
1 Start to do something...
1 Cancelled to do something...
2 Start to do something...
3 Start to do something...
2 Finished to do something...
3 Finished to do something...
```

But what I want to achieve is this output:

```
1 Start to do something...
1 Cancelled to do something...
2 Start to do something...
2 Cancelled to do something...
3 Start to do something...
3 Finished to do something...
```

My current solution is the following:

```
private async Task RestartAsync()
{
    if (_isRestarting)
    {
        return;
    }

    _cts.Cancel();
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    _isRestarting = true;
    await _somethingIsRunningTask;
    _isRestarting = false;

    _somethingIsRunningTask = DoSomethingAsync(_cts.Token);

    await _somethingIsRunningTask;
}
```

Then I get this output:

```
1 Start to do something...
1 Cancelled to do something...
2 Start to do something...
2 Finished to do something...
```

Now at least `DoSomethingAsync` is not started while it is still in progress (Note that third run is ignored, which does not really matter, because it should cancel the second run otherwise).

But this solution doesn't feel good and I have to repeat this ugly pattern wherever I want this kind of behavior. **Is there any good pattern or framework for this kind of restart mechanic?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is inside RestartAsync method. Beware that an async method will immediately return a task if it's going to await something, so second RestartAsync actually return before it swap its task then third RestartAsync comes in and awaiting the task first RestartAsync.

Also if RestartAsync is going to be executed by multiple thread, you may want to wrap _cts and _somethingIsRunningTask into one and swap values with Interlocked.Exchange method to prevent race condition.

Here is my example code, not fully tested:

```
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        RestartTaskDemo restartTaskDemo = new RestartTaskDemo();

        Task[] tasks = { restartTaskDemo.RestartAsync( 1000 ), restartTaskDemo.RestartAsync( 1000 ), restartTaskDemo.RestartAsync( 1000 ) };
        await Task.WhenAll( tasks );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class RestartTaskDemo
{
    private int Counter = 0;

    private TaskEntry PreviousTask = new TaskEntry( Task.CompletedTask, new CancellationTokenSource() );

    public async Task RestartAsync( int delay )
    {            
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        TaskEntry previousTaskEntry = Interlocked.Exchange( ref PreviousTask, new TaskEntry( taskCompletionSource.Task, cancellationTokenSource ) );

        previousTaskEntry.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        await previousTaskEntry.Task.ContinueWith( Continue );

        async Task Continue( Task previousTask )
        {
            try
            {
                await DoworkAsync( delay, cancellationTokenSource.Token );
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult( true );
            }
            catch( TaskCanceledException )
            {
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
            }
        }            
    }

    private async Task DoworkAsync( int delay, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        int count = Interlocked.Increment( ref Counter );
        Console.WriteLine( $"Task {count} started." );

        try
        {
            await Task.Delay( delay, cancellationToken );
            Console.WriteLine( $"Task {count} finished." );
        }
        catch( TaskCanceledException )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( $"Task {count} cancelled." );
            throw;
        }
    }

    private class TaskEntry
    {
        public Task Task { get; }

        public CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; }

        public TaskEntry( Task task, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource )
        {
            Task = task;
            CancellationTokenSource = cancellationTokenSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution and the hint with the thread safety (although restart is always called from the UI thread in my case)

I don't understand why you call `ContinueWith`. Why not just await `previousTaskEntry.Task`?

Comment: You can await previousTaskEntry.Task with a empty try-catch, it should provide same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is a concurrency problem. So, you'll need a solution for concurrency problems: a semaphore.

In the generic case, you should account also for when the method being runs throws an `OperationCanceledException`:

```
private async Task DoSomethingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _numberOfStarts++;
    int numberOfStarts = _numberOfStarts;

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfStarts + " Start to do something...");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // This operation can not be cancelled.
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfStarts + " Finished to do something...");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfStarts + " Cancelled to do something...");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
private (CancellationTokenSource cts, Task task)? state;

private async Task RestartAsync()
{
    Task task = null;

    await this.semaphore.WaitAsync();

    try
    {
        if (this.state.HasValue)
        {
            this.state.Value.cts.Cancel();
            this.state.Value.cts.Dispose();

            try
            {
                await this.state.Value.task;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }

            this.state = null;
        }

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        task = DoSomethingAsync(cts.Token);

        this.state = (cts, task);
    }
    finally
    {
        this.semaphore.Release();
    }

    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Although I better like to await the previous task, then a semaphore, because it better represents what I want to achieve like suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54102382/3446784

But it's a matter of taste.

I think it is also no real concurrency problem, because the method is always called from the UI thread in reality, so no other thread is involved.

Comment: It is waiting all tasks. If there was no concurrency, you wouldn't need to cancel the previous execution.